# Split ringer and notification volume on Android 4.2?

Tags: android, notifications, android-4.2-jelly-bean

Is there any option how to split this volumes programmatically or some app? Some apps ( Smart Sound Profiles, Sound Profile and many others) says they can split notification and ringer, but ANY really works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're asking exactly.  Android maintains audio streams that have separate volumes.  Each of these streams can be set separately.  To set the volume use an audio manager and setStreamVolume().  Checkout this class http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html Each static variable STREAM_XXXX is a reference to that audio stream.

Update based on comments:

If there may be a setting under system settings > sound options > volume that will set it to use incoming call volume for notifications.  This is dependent on individual phones and manufacturer modifications, so you might have to hunt for it.

Comment: I know. But when you use this:     setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING... it also affects notification volume

Comment: Ok, now I see what you mean.  This is probably highly dependent on individual phones and manufacturer modifications.  Based on my emulator, if you go into your sound settings > volume there is a checkbox for "Use incoming call volume for notifications"

Comment: Did this work for you?  If so would you mind giving an up vote / accept?

Answer (score 0):

The stock Nexus 4 has no such options to adjust the notifications independent of the ringer volume.  I understand the stock Galaxy Nexus has the same issue.  The only way that I know to get this feature "back" is to root and install a custom ROM or utilize a 3rd party app such as   [Sound Profile](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=Orion.Soft&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsIk9yaW9uLlNvZnQiXQ..) but I didn't have great success with it.